# How to show the solution of a complex ODE must be on a line?

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers, dynamical-systems, complex-integration

I have an ODE of a complex variable,
$$z'(t) = R(t)(c-z(t))$$
where $c$ is a complex constant, $z(0)$ is a complex number and $R(t)$ is an unknown real function with $0<R(t)<\infty$.

Since $R(t)$ is unknown, I do not expect to solve $z(t)$ explicitly. But I think the solution $z(t)$ must lie on the line from $z(0)$ to $c$ as $R(t)>0$, which only controls the speed of $z(t)$ approaching $c$.

To prove the that, I thought about using the mean-value theorem for integral but didn't get fruitful results.

Can anyone please give me a hint?

Comment: Actually, you can check that $z(t)=c-e^{-S(t)}+cte$, where $S$ is a primitive of $R$ (this is a separate variable ODE)

Comment: Thanks! That's a very useful hint!